# UIScrollView doesn't remember the position

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios4, ios, uiscrollviewdelegate

Has anyone ever had the problem that a `UIScrollView`, which gets moved by `[UIScrollView setContentOffset:...]` doesn't "remember" it's new position? It however does, if the user scrolls via touch-and-drag.

**Symptoms:** If the `UIScrollView` doesn't remember the new position, it "flips" back to the original position it last remembers (which is the position which has been used via touch-and-drag) whenever it's being touched.

**Interesting:**

- This only **happens in 4.0** and
  didn't happen in 3.1
- This only happens if `pagingEnabled == YES` is
  set

Comment: doesn't ring a bell. Are you sure there is no other explanation? Are frames and bounds all correct and have you logged all setContentOffsets you may be doing?

Comment: post some code please, as mvds suggests you can do something wrong

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the `contentInsets` would confuse the `contentOffsets` in iOS 4.0 ... must be a bug in the SDK?

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?