# I do not want the scroll view back up by itself

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have a scroll view with a list of items but the scroll does not fill the screen, only half because I want the title above and below the buttons are always visible, and have designed the scroll as I want but when you release the tap always returns to the beginning and do not want to do that but I do not know how.

```
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];
```

[image: The red rectangle is the image scroll view but I can not see the data that is on the bottom as you release the scroll back to the top]

The red rectangle in the image is the scroll view but I can not see the data that is on the bottom as you release the scroll back to the top

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: The red rectangle in the image is the scroll view but I can not see the data that is on the bottom as you release the scroll back to the top in the run mode

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Comment: no back-up to drop the scrollview

Comment: check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480512/uiscrollview-single-tap-scrolls-it-to-top