# UIScrollView scrolls to top on touch

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Seems like this has been asked [**before**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480512/uiscrollview-single-tap-scrolls-it-to-top) but I tried all the solutions but they don't seem to work. I tried both the solutions :

```
if scrollView.isPagingEnabled {
    if scrollView.scrollToBottom() == true {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
    }
} else {
    if scrollView.scrollToBottom() == false {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}
```

**And**

```
scrollView.isPagingEnabled = self.scroll_course_detail.contentOffset.y < (self.scroll_course_detail.contentSize.height - self.scroll_course_detail.frame.size.height)
```

Here are the values which I get in the logs :

```
print("self.contentSize.height : \(self.contentSize.height)")
print("self.frame.size.height : \(self.frame.size.height)")
print("self.contentOffset.y : \(self.contentOffset.y)")
```

> self.contentSize.height : 597.405
>   self.frame.size.height : 520.0
>   self.contentOffset.y : 75.0

The difference between `self.contentSize.height` and `self.frame.size.height` comes out to be **77.405** (not 75). And I cannot do a static check by adding that **extra 2.405** since that would not handle other cases.
I cannot disable paging for scrollView since I am using it.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question, as what you currently have doesn't make any sense. Where are you executing `scrollView.isPagingEnabled = ...`? What does `scrollView.scrollToBottom()` do that it returns a boolean value? When are you printing height and contentOffset values? What are you actually trying to do?